# Cross-Domain POST XRSF Token Inquiry

Tags: javascript, http-post, roblox

```
function crossDomainPost() {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  var uniqueString = "CHANGE_THIS_TO_SOME_UNIQUE_STRING";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.style.display = "none";
  iframe.contentWindow.name = uniqueString;

  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.target = uniqueString;
  form.action = "http://www.roblox.com/groups/api/change-member-rank?groupId=1223714&newRoleSetId=8113155&targetUserId=58806949";
  form.method = "POST";

  // repeat for each parameter
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "hidden";
  input.name = "INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME_HERE";
  input.value = "INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_VALUE_HERE";
  form.appendChild(input);

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}

crossDomainPost()
```

This is the output error:

```
POST http://www.roblox.com/groups/api/change-member-rank?groupId=1223714&newRoleSetId=8113155&targetUserId=58806949 403 (XSRF Token Validation Failed)
```

How exactly would I make this not pop up?

I'm extremely new to cross-domain POST requests.

I don't need to send any data with it..

Comment: This is by design... [Same Origin Policy](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: Depending on what you want to do you can get around it by running the script in the console of a http://www.roblox.com site or use PHP and cURL on your own site.